# how to integrate jmeter script with azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines

how to integrate jmeter script with azure devops pipeline?
I am new in azure devops,give some insight view for this?
I  have pushed the jmeter code to azure devops repo and then created build for that but afterthat how can I integrate with pipeline.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What hasn't worked? Did you read any documentation?

Comment: Just want to check whether below expression is work for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/executing-jmeter-tests-in-an-azure-pipeline/

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure which exactly part you want to know, here just provide you the basic application in VSTS.

Until now, there still has 3 load testing tasks can for you use to integrate the Jmeter: [Cloud-based Load Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/cloud-based-load-test?view=azure-devops), [Cloud-based Web Performance Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/cloud-based-web-performance-test?view=azure-devops) and [Apache JMeter Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/run-jmeter-load-test?view=azure-devops). These 3 tasks can all be used in CI and CD.

But, there one thing you need pay attention that we are **gradually deprecating** [Cloud load testing(CLT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops#cloud-based-load-testing-service-clt-availability-timeframe-for):

> 1. **Existing customers of CLT**:
>
> For existing Azure DevOps customers using cloud-load testing
>   functionality in the Azure DevOps portal, this feature will no longer
>   be available as of **March 31, 2020**.
>
> For existing Azure customers using the performance test feature in App
>   Services or Application Insights, this feature will no longer be
>   available as of **March 31, 2020**.
>
> For Visual Studio users leveraging cloud-based load testing, this
>   feature will no longer be supported as of **March 31, 2020**. Visual
>   Studio Enterprise customers can, however, continue to run load tests
>   on-premises using Test Controller/Test Agent and will be supported for
>   any issues that may arise during the support lifecycle of the Visual
>   Studio version.
>
> 2. **New customers of CLT**:
>
> New Azure DevOps organizations and new Azure subscriptions created
>   after **March 31st, 2019** will not have access to the cloud-based load
>   testing functionality.

Since until now, we are still support these tasks, you could see and choose them in Deprecated tasks panel:

[image]

Then you can follow above task document to configure your test task.

Below are another blog and docs you could take as refer:

- [Configuring Jmeter Tests in VSTS/TFS (Azure DevOps) and publishing
  Results](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9)
- [Run Apache JMeter load tests with Test plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=azure-devops)
- [Using a self-service model for load test and cloud-load testing,
  e.g. Apache JMeter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/overview?view=azure-devops#alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern described in the post can be considered as well: https://medium.com/@maninder.bindra/load-testing-in-azdo-pipeline-using-dynamically-created-azure-container-instance-with-apache-bench-d4c3e1f9dc

In this approach a load inducing Azure Container instance is  created (as part of pipeline, with Apache Bench or JMeter installed, and in a different AzDO agent pool) for the duration of the Load Test, and after the Load test results have been recorded the ACI instance is deleted.

It has been indicated in the post where you would need to make changes to the pipeline yaml if JMeter needs to be used instead of Apache Bench. Hope it helps.